# Escaping "new line" character in SRT file

Tags: encoding, subtitles, escape-characters

I'm trying to display "\n" in an .SRT file, but VLC automatically interprets it as a carriage return, though I want to display it in a raw way. I've tried combinations like "\\n" or adding quotes, but nothing seems to work. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: what about `\\n` ?

Comment: That's what I first tried, as mentioned in my post (I just realized that I wrote just one "\"), but still no luck.

Comment: EDIT : I did write "\\n" but this website reformatted it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this by pasting a special symbol between "\" and "n".
I tried Word Joiner symbol (`U+2060`) - works. Copy this -> "`\⁠n`".
Also tried with Zero Width Space (​​​`U+200B`) - works. Copy this -> "`\​n`".
Also wanted to try with Zero Width No-Break space (U+FEFF), but was not able to copy it to clipboard. In KCharSelect there is no UTF-8 representation for it (only for utf-16).

Also tried xml entities for backslash (`&#x5c;`, `&#92;`, `&#0092;`), but they are printed literally in vlc version 3.0.18.

Comment: See also bug report: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10356